# How to fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function error

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = streamCourses({
      next: (querySnapshot) => {
        const task = querySnapshot.docs.map((docSnapshot) => 
            mapDocTask(docSnapshot)
          );
        setCourseDetails(task);
      },
      error: (error) => console.log(error),
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [setCourseDetails]);
```

Comment: HI please include some details of the scenario you are having with. It will help us understand your question

Comment: Why is there a `setCourseDetails` there? And what does it do?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue to this. What I had to do to solve it was two things:

(1) I created a `State` boolean `isMounted` which was set to `true` by default and was used to wrap the contents of my `useEffect`s so that the contents of my `useEffect`s would only run if the screen was `mounted`.

(2) I created a `useEffect` dedicated solely to cleanup. Meaning this `useEffect` had nothing besides a `return` statement in it which set the various `State` variables I had to their default values.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted) {
        const unsubscribe = streamCourses({
          next: (querySnapshot) => {
            const task = querySnapshot.docs.map((docSnapshot) => 
                mapDocTask(docSnapshot)
              );
            setCourseDetails(task);
          },
          error: (error) => console.log(error),
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }
  }, [setCourseDetails]);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        setCourseDetails(null);
        setIsMounted(false);
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: **I fixed that error with the above guidance. Thank you very much for your help.**